# Let $G$ be a regular graph with $n = 2m$ vertices. Prove if $|E(G)| \ge m^2$, then $G$ is Hamiltonian.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am not sure how to prove this. Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that each vertex of $G$ has degree $d$; then $2md=2|E(G)|$, so $md=|E(G)|\ge m^2$. Now apply [Ore’s Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ore%27s_theorem) (or [Dirac’s Theorem](http://faculty.wwu.edu/sarkara/dirac.pdf)).